# MySQL query and EXISTS clause

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to return `operacao='DELETE'` if it exists or, if it doesn't exist, return the same as it returns now. Now query returns the first 'operacao' that is found.

Lets say that I need to know that operacao also 'DELETE' exists.

```
SELECT A.*, wf.RHID as rhidwf, wf.operacao as operacao  
from (
  SELECT 
    CONCAT(RHID) AS pk, RHID, CD_DOC_ID, SEQ, NR_DOCUMENTO, EMISSOR,
    DT_EMISSAO, DT_VALIDADE 
  FROM rh_id_documentos   
  WHERE RHID='6' AND CD_DOC_ID='1' AND SEQ='1') A 
LEFT JOIN fo_on_workflow wf  ON A.pk = wf.RHID 
GROUP BY  A.RHID, A.CD_DOC_ID, A.SEQ;
```

Comment: This is extremely unclear. Better show on some example.

Comment: I ve create a fiddle   http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7704f4/1

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT A.*
    ,wf.RHID AS rhidwf
    ,wf.operacao AS operacao
FROM (  

    SELECT CONCAT ('%',RHID,'>%') AS pk
        ,RHID
        ,CD_DOC_ID
        ,SEQ
        ,NR_DOCUMENTO
        ,EMISSOR
        ,DT_EMISSAO
        ,DT_VALIDADE
    FROM rh_id_documentos 
    WHERE RHID = '6'
        AND CD_DOC_ID = '1'
        AND SEQ = '1'
  ) A
LEFT JOIN fo_on_workflow wf ON  wf.RHID LIKE A.pk 
ORDER BY operacao LIMIT 1
```